# getElementsByTagName - target pair of 2 different tags - can't get for loop working

Tags: javascript, html, unobtrusive-javascript

I have pairs of `h2` and `div` (there is another tag between each pair), which I want to target so that when the `h2` is clicked it changes the class of the `div` (unobtrusively and without using any `ids` or `classes` to find the tags). I've got this working for 1 pair, all I've got to do now is to put in a `for` loop to iterate through all pairs which you'd think should be easy, but I just can't get it working!

**The working script for the first pair:**

```
var list = document.getElementsByTagName('h2');

var i = 0;

list[i].onclick = function() {
    toggleNews(i); 
}

function toggleNews(index) {
    var news = document.getElementsByTagName('div')[index]  
    if ( news.className.match(/(?:^|\s)hometext-show(?!\S)/) )
    news.className = "hometext";
    else
    news.className += " hometext-show";
}
```

Basically, I just need to replace `var i = 0;` by `for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++)` - or so I thought - but however I place `{` and `}` it won't work (nothing happens when clicking).

I don't want to use `jquery`.

---

**Update:** Thank you so much for pointing me in the right direction, as I had no clue what to search for.

Below is a fully working script (now I just need to understand *why* you have to do like this):

```
var list = document.getElementsByTagName('h2');

for (var i=0; i<list.length; i++) {
    list[i].onclick = createfunc(i);
}

function createfunc(i) {
    return function() {
        toggleNews(i); 
    }
}

function toggleNews(index) {
    var news = document.getElementsByTagName('div')[index]
    if ( news.className.match(/(?:^|\s)hometext-show(?!\S)/) )
    news.className = "hometext";
    else
    news.className += " hometext-show";
}
```

Comment: How do you mean it won't work?  What errors or other indications are you getting?

Comment: When using a for loop you need to bind the current value of `i` to the onclick handler with a closure or else `toggleNews` will always run with with the highest index value.  See [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction, I've now added the solution myself.